# I don't want p:commandLink redirect

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

Could someone explain me why the following commandLink is redirecting?

```
<p:commandLink value="#{popupMsg['painel.informacoes.conta.alterar']}"
               actionListener="#{controladorPopupSelecaoConta.abrir}"
               oncomplete="exibirPopup(xhr,status,args,dlgselecaoConta);"
               title="#{popupMsg['painel.informacoes.conta.alterar.descricao']}"
               update=":selecaoConta :alerta" process="@none"/>
```

if I put the same element, without any modification, in another existent h:form, it works like expected (open a dialog).

Comment: That can happen if there's a JS error (as it does the job by JS). Did you pay attention to JS console?

Comment: There is no error in chrome console neither exceptions in glassfish

Comment: Well, then it's time to create and post an SSCCE so that we (and yourself!) can reproduce the exact problem by just copy'n'paste'n'running the snippet into a blank playground project without any (non-obvious) modifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was creating SSCCE project to share here, I noticed that the xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" was not declared in the file I was using the p:commandLink. So I came from this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:hrgi="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/hrgi">

<ui:component>
     <h:form>
        <p:commandLink value="#{popupMsg['painel.informacoes.conta.alterar']}"
                   actionListener="#{controladorPopupSelecaoConta.abrir}"
                   oncomplete="exibirPopup(xhr,status,args,dlgselecaoConta);"
                   title="#{popupMsg['painel.informacoes.conta.alterar.descricao']}"
                   update=":selecaoConta :alerta" process="@none"/>
    </h:form>
</ui:component>
</html>
```

to this:

```
<ui:component xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
          xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
          xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:form>
        <p:commandLink value="#{popupMsg['painel.informacoes.conta.alterar']}"
                   actionListener="#{controladorPopupSelecaoConta.abrir}"
                   oncomplete="exibirPopup(xhr,status,args,dlgselecaoConta);"
                   title="#{popupMsg['painel.informacoes.conta.alterar.descricao']}"
                   update=":selecaoConta :alerta" process="@none"/>
    </h:form>
</ui:component>
```